# Error using Quarkus Panache Entities with Generic Java programming

Tags: hibernate, rest, generics, quarkus

I am trying to create a very known generic resource for my Panache Entities, however, it does not seem to play well with Java generics. What I wanted to do is avoid repeat myself with common REST operation. I want to change the HTTP meta info (like: auth or not, the resource path, etc), but all the time the actual response building is the same, so I built this generic class:

```
package org.reproducer;

import java.net.URI;
import java.util.List;

import javax.transaction.Transactional;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder;

import io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.panache.PanacheEntity;

public class BaseResource<T extends PanacheEntity> {

    public List<T> listAll() {
        return T.listAll();
    }

    public Response get(long id) {
        T entity = T.findById(id);
        if (entity != null) {
            return Response.ok(entity).build();
        } else {
            return notFound(id);
        }
    }

    @Transactional
    public Response add(T entity) {
        T.persist(entity);
        URI uri = UriBuilder.fromPath("/")
                // "this" reference was not working here
                .path(entity.getClass().getName().toLowerCase()).path("{id}").build(entity.id);
        return Response.created(uri).build();
    }

    @Transactional
    public Response remove(long id) {
        T entity = T.findById(id);
        if (entity != null) {
            entity.delete();
            return Response.noContent().build();
        } else {
            return notFound(id);
        }
    }

    private Response notFound(long id) {
        return Response.status(404).entity("Entity with id " + id + " not found.").build();
    }

}
```

So I could extend and focus on the REST/HTTP part in my resource:

```
import java.util.List;

import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.DELETE;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

import org.reproducer.model.TheEntity;

@Path("/entity2")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class ResourceWithBase extends BaseResource<TheEntity>{

    @GET
    public List<TheEntity> listAll() {
        return super.listAll();
    }

    @GET
    @Path("{id}")
    public Response get(@PathParam("id") long id) {
        return super.get(id);
    }

    @POST
    public Response add(TheEntity entity) {
        return super.add(entity);
    }

    @DELETE
    @Path("{id}")
    public Response remove(@PathParam("id") long id) {
        return super.remove(id);
    }

}
```

However, whatever I try to call any of the methods it will fail with:

However, whatever I try to call any of the methods it will fail with `This method is normally automatically overridden in subclasses: did you forget to annotate your entity with @Entity?` (full stack trace below

```
ERROR: Exception handling request fcc704b2-25f9-4fac-b60e-3dd1f25a7c7c-1 to /entity2
org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This method is normally automatically overridden in subclasses: did you forget to annotate your entity with @Entity?
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler.handleApplicationException(ExceptionHandler.java:106)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler.handleException(ExceptionHandler.java:372)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.writeException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:209)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:496)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$invoke$4(SynchronousDispatcher.java:252)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$preprocess$0(SynchronousDispatcher.java:153)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.PreMatchContainerRequestContext.filter(PreMatchContainerRequestContext.java:363)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.preprocess(SynchronousDispatcher.java:156)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:238)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:249)
    at io.quarkus.resteasy.runtime.ResteasyFilter$ResteasyResponseWrapper.sendError(ResteasyFilter.java:64)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.DefaultServlet.doGet(DefaultServlet.java:175)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:686)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:791)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:74)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)
    at io.quarkus.resteasy.runtime.ResteasyFilter.doFilter(ResteasyFilter.java:28)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:68)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:132)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:292)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:138)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:135)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at io.quarkus.undertow.runtime.UndertowDeploymentRecorder$8$1$1.call(UndertowDeploymentRecorder.java:489)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:272)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:104)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:364)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:830)
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2011)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1535)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1395)
    at org.jboss.threads.DelegatingRunnable.run(DelegatingRunnable.java:29)
    at org.jboss.threads.ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.run(ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.java:29)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:479)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This method is normally automatically overridden in subclasses: did you forget to annotate your entity with @Entity?
    at io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.panache.runtime.JpaOperations.implementationInjectionMissing(JpaOperations.java:351)
    at io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.panache.PanacheEntityBase.listAll(PanacheEntityBase.java:355)
    at org.reproducer.BaseResource.listAll(BaseResource.java:15)
    at org.reproducer.ResourceWithBase.listAll(ResourceWithBase.java:24)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:151)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.lambda$invoke$3(MethodInjectorImpl.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniApply(CompletableFuture.java:602)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniApplyStage(CompletableFuture.java:614)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.thenApply(CompletableFuture.java:1983)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.thenApply(CompletableFuture.java:110)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:122)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.internalInvokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:580)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTargetAfterFilter(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:454)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.lambda$invokeOnTarget$2(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:408)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.PreMatchContainerRequestContext.filter(PreMatchContainerRequestContext.java:363)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:410)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:379)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.lambda$invoke$1(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:353)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniComposeStage(CompletableFuture.java:981)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.thenCompose(CompletableFuture.java:2124)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.thenCompose(CompletableFuture.java:110)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:353)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:477)
    ... 49 more
```

I tried different approaches, like using repository, an interface to define the methods and others. Always fails in a different way, it seems that Panache does not like generics or the panache extension does not implement a way to generate code for T.{some panache static method}!

Is this expected? Do you suggest any workaround to make it work?

The code for a reproducer can be found here ->  https://github.com/jesuino/reproducers/tree/master/quarkus-panache-generics

I hate having to repeat code for this!

Comment: I will check out your reproducer and let you know if I come up with anything

Comment: OK, I think this is a known issue. Can you open a issue on the Quarkus github repo in order to continue the discussion there?

Comment: Hello @geoand - sorry the delay, I missed your comments. - I created this issue -> https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/3632

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I copy/paste here the answer I made on the Github Issue

What you want to do cannot works, it's not a limitation on Panache but on the way Java Generics works.

On your reproducer I saw this:

```
public class BaseResource<T extends PanacheEntity> {
    public List<T> listAll() {
        return T.listAll();
    }
}

public class ResourceWithBase extends BaseResource<TheEntity>{
    @GET
    public List<TheEntity> listAll() {
        return super.listAll();
```

}
}

Even if `T` seems to be of type `TheEntity`, at runtime it isn't, as T extends PancheEntity, the runtime class is `PanacheEntity` so you try to call the `listAll()` methods on `PanacheEntity` and it can not works.

This is the way static methods works on generic types in Java.

Saying it in another way: you call listAll() on T not on TheEntity as listAll() is a static method so it is linked to the type not the instance.